# Is the fundamental relationship between electromagnetism & gravity unknown?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, unified-theories

Richard Feynman made the following statement:

> the relationship between the gravity forces and electrical forces
> remains unknown

[in the interview linked here](https://youtu.be/36GT2zI8lVA?t=423).

In context, he made this statement partly as to contrast the well-known relationship between magnetism & electricity.

[As I have read](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/136755/150180), the energy in the electromagnetic field contributes to gravity by affecting spacetime curvature, which surely Feynman would have understood. So what might he have been referring to instead?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387/2451

Answer (score 1):

> the energy in the electromagnetic field contributes to gravity by affecting spacetime curvature, which surely Feynman would have understood

That's for sure.
I think he meant if gravity can be derived from the e.m. field, or the other way round. In the twenties (of last century, obviously), Kaluza and Klein proposed a five-dimensional spacetime to include electromagnetism (not knowing they laid the foundations for modern string theory). You can Google for this theory.